# Decoding a Rewritten URL using mod_rewrite - htaccess - regex

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am using Apache 2.4. I have set up and configured an Apache HTTP server, to host my invision app, my app is linked to external google docs. I am trying to redirect to an external google doc from the app but Apache does not like it.

This is the URL it tries to access

```
http://example.com/redirect? 
url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fforms%2Fd%2Fe%2F1234567890%2Fviewform
```

I have Rewritten the URL using the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)(forms.+)
RewriteRule ^redirect(.*) https://docs.google.com/%2 [R=302,QSD]
```

and after the rewrite, I am left with this.

```
https://docs.google.com/forms%2Fd%2Fe%2F12345678900%Fviewform
```

This does what it is supposed to and if I personally replace the %2F with '/' it brings me to the document so I know it is close. The URL redirects to google drive, only I get a

> 404 page not found

message from google drive. I know I need to decode the URL in order to successfully reach the document but how can I do this using .htaccess or any other means?

```
AllowEncodedSlahes on (I have also tried NoDecode) //VirtualHost conf and apache conf
```

I have tried matching and replacing the %2F's using Regex but they are not recognized and I get 500 - Internal Server Error.

I understand that this seems to be an ongoing bug/issue but does anyone at all have a solution to this incredibly painful problem please? I am at my wits end with this, Thank you.

Comment: Can you please include the requested URL you are matching.

Comment: @MrWhite I have edited my question to include the requested URL that I am matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and after the rewrite, I am left with this.
>
> ```
> https://docs.google.com/forms%2Fd%2Fe%2F12345678900%Fviewform
> ```

Although that wouldn't happen with the directives you posted, unless you also included the `NE` (`noescape`) flag on the `RewriteRule` directive. (Instead, it would be *doubly encoded*). Using the `NE` flag is a step in the right direction, however, we need another step to URL decode the resulting URL-path...

*Side note:* The resulting URL-path you posted above has a typo (given your example input URL). The final `%2F` is missing; instead, you have `0%F`. It should read: `forms%2Fd%2Fe%2F1234567890%2Fviewform`

Google would seem to be triggering the 404 because of the encoded slashes in the URL-path (as you suggest), just as Apache will do by default. Setting `AllowEncodedSlashes On` (in the vHost) will not immediately help with this as the 404 is being triggered by Google. However, this does need to be set so we can process the URL further and unencode the encoded slashes, before issuing the final redirect.

Try the following instead:

```
# Set in your vhost (server config)
AllowEncodedSlashes On
```

Then, in `.htaccess` (or appropriate `<Directory>` section):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)(forms.+)
RewriteRule ^redirect$ /redirect/%2 [NE,QSD]
RewriteRule ^redirect/(.+) https://docs.google.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

So, given an initial request to *your server* of:

```
/redirect?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fforms%2Fd%2Fe%2F1234567890%2Fviewform
```

1. The first `RewriteRule` *internally rewrites* the request to (still on your server):

   ```
   /redirect/forms%2Fd%2Fe%2F1234567890%2Fviewform
   ```

   This is "allowed" (and does not trigger a 404) because of the `AllowEncodedSlashes On` directive you have set in the server config.
2. Then, the second `RewriteRule` decodes the URL-path (`%2F` to `/`) and issues an external redirect to:

   ```
   https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1234567890/viewform
   ```

   Apache automatically URL decodes the URL-path before the `RewriteRule` *pattern* is applied. The relevant part is captured and passed through to the *substitution* in the `$1` backreference.

Comment: If I could UpVote this 1000 times I would. Perfect solution that works exactly how I wanted it too. Also because of your detailed answer I understand exactly what's happening at each step and why it is happening. Excellent. Thank you very much.